# spresense でマイク入力のピン番号を選択するには？

Tags: spresense

spresenseにマイクを1本使用して音声を入力をする際に、拡張ボードのマイクAのみしか選択できず悩んでおります。

現状、マイクA、Bにはそれぞれ3.5mmジャックを、マイクC、DにはそれそれBNC端子を接続しており必要に応じてどれか1つ(もしくは2つ)の端子を使用することを想定しています。

マイク入力ピンの番号(A～D)を選択するにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか。

ご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

マイクの選択は、SDKでは、以下に記載があります。

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_baseband_set_command

SetMicMap　0x5e　SetMicMapCmplt　使用するマイクの選択・順番を設定します。

このマイクのチャンネルマップは、
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_MIC_CHANNEL_SELECT_MAP

ここにあるような、8byteの設定のようです。

```
typedef struct
{
  /*! \brief [in] Set Mic mapping
   *
   *   mic_map[ch(0 <= ch < AS_MIC_CHANNEL_MAX] correspond to
   *   each channels, and you can map analog and digital Mics.
   *
   *   0x1 : Analog Mic 1
   *   0x2 : Analog Mic 2 
   *   0x3 : Analog Mic 3
   *   0x4 : Analog Mic 4
   *   0x5 : Digital Mic 1
   *   0x6 : Digital Mic 2
   *   0x7 : Digital Mic 3
   *   0x8 : Digital Mic 4
   *   0x9 : Digital Mic 5
   *   0xA : Digital Mic 6
   *   0xB : Digital Mic 7
   *   0xC : Digital Mic 8
   *   other : No assing
   *
   */

  uint8_t mic_map[AS_MIC_CHANNEL_MAX]; 

} SetMicMapParam;
```

ABとCDを入れ替えて使う場合は、

```
  AudioCommand command;

  command.header.packet_length = LENGTH_SETMICMAP;
  command.header.command_code  = AUDCMD_SETMICMAP;
  command.header.sub_code      = 0;

  command.set_mic_map_param.mic_map = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };

  AS_SendAudioCommand( &command );
```

と

```
  AudioCommand command;

  command.header.packet_length = LENGTH_SETMICMAP;
  command.header.command_code  = AUDCMD_SETMICMAP;
  command.header.sub_code      = 0;

  command.set_mic_map_param.mic_map = { 03, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };

  AS_SendAudioCommand( &command );
```

とし、2chで録音すれば、マイクがABとCDで切り替わりそうです。

また、Arduinoの場合は、マイク順の変更には対応されていないようですが、
Audio.h の中にある、

```
err_t AudioClass::set_mic_map(uint8_t map[AS_MIC_CHANNEL_MAX])
{
  AudioCommand command;

  command.header.packet_length = LENGTH_SETMICMAP;
  command.header.command_code  = AUDCMD_SETMICMAP;
  command.header.sub_code      = 0;

  memcpy(command.set_mic_map_param.mic_map, map, sizeof(command.set_mic_map_param.mic_map));

  AS_SendAudioCommand( &command );

  AudioResult result;
  AS_ReceiveAudioResult(&result);

  if (result.header.result_code != AUDRLT_SETMICMAPCMPLT)
    {
      print_err("ERROR: Command(0x%x) fails. Result code(0x%x) Module id(%d) Error code(0x%lx) subcode(0x%lx)\n",
                command.header.command_code, result.header.result_code, result.error_response_param.module_id,
                result.error_response_param.error_code, result.error_response_param.error_sub_code);
      print_dbg("ERROR: %s\n", error_msg[result.error_response_param.error_code]);
      return AUDIOLIB_ECODE_AUDIOCOMMAND_ERROR;
    }

  return AUDIOLIB_ECODE_OK;
}
```

というプライベート関数があるので、こちら呼べるようにしてしまえば、
変更が可能になりそうです。

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

Arduinoの場合、MediaRecorderクラスを使うと、こちらの記事にあるように、マイクのマッピングが変更できそうです。

ここでいう、

uint32_t mic_map = 0x56789abc;
CXD56_AUDIO_ECODE error_code = cxd56_audio_set_micmap(mic_map);

を

uint32_t mic_map = 0x21;
CXD56_AUDIO_ECODE error_code = cxd56_audio_set_micmap(mic_map);

か、

uint32_t mic_map = 0x43;
CXD56_AUDIO_ECODE error_code = cxd56_audio_set_micmap(mic_map);

に変える感じでしょうか。

http://spresense.livedoor.blog/archives/21028830.html